# Return to main thread as soon as one child thread throws an exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice

I'm using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and `invokeAll` with a List of `Callable`s to do long-running multithreaded processing.
My main thread is blocked until all threads did finish and I can process the Futures returned by `invokeAll`. I'd like however `invokeAll` to immediately return if one of the `Callable`s throw an exception and terminate the other threads.

Using `execute` instead of `invokeAll` would block on the first `future.get()` which needs not to be the one that throws the execption.

Using busy waiting to loop through all the futures and checking `isDone()` seems not to be the best way either.

Comment: have you tried shutting down the executos service and having it interrupt the other tasks? if those other tasks dont wait/read they could still check the thread interruption flag every now and then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use more complex synchronization mechanisms like latches, barriers or semaphores, but have a look at [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). It's a lightweight wrapper around `ExecutorService` that allows you to listen for the *first* finished task. Here is a quick example:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = 
            new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executorService);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    completionService.submit(new Task());
}
completionService.take().get();
```

The code is pretty simple. First you wrap `executorService` with `completionService`. Later you use it to submit tasks one after another. The last line is crucial. It takes the first task that finished and tries to retrieve the result. If it thrown an exception, it will be rethrown here, wrapped with `ExecutionException`:

```
try {
    completionService.take().get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.getCause();       //this was thrown from task!
}
```

Inside `catch` block you can somehow handle the exception, e.g. canceling remaining tasks or shutting down the whole thread pool.

Of course you are free to wait for all tasks to finish by calling `take()` ten times. Each call will block as long as there is at least one task finished.

Comment: And how will you terminate the rest of the threads upon exception?

Comment: @zaske: each `submit()` returns `Future<T>`. If you encounter an exception, you can just iterate over all futures and `cancel()` them.

Comment: @ Tomasz Nurkiewicz - But how will the caller of the completion service take method understand an exception has occured?

Comment: @zaske: the .get() throws an ExecutionException then.

Comment: To be able to re use the thread pool for multiple iterations, people might also want to look at ListeningExecutorService/ListenableFuture